# SPI SDHC card will not come ready, Regular (older) SD card works fine

Tags: spi, sd

I am trying to make an SPI interface  on a 186 Microprocessor using bit banging and a GPIO  to control the CS, SCLK, MOSI and reading in the MISO lines.  Mode 0.
I cannot get SDHC  (version2) cards to intialise to the ready state. Older SD cards work fine.

So my init sequence is as follows:

- Plug in the  SD card into a live socket
- wait ~100ms
- start initialization (CS, MOSI  high + send 100 clock)
- then every command has the following sequence..
  8 Clocks
  CS LOW
  8 clocks
  CMD0 (arg:0, crc:0x95) + wait R1 response
  8 more clocks
  CS High
  8 more clocks
- Same sequence for CMD8 as follows...

(a) For the older SD cards  CMD8  gives illegal
Then I send a sequence of CMD01  which initially give an 01h R1 and eventually give 00h -- indicating the card is ready.

(b) For the newer SDHC commands I get  ..
CMD8 (arg:0x000001AA, crc:0x87) + wait R1 + arg echo response

Then ..

- CMD55 (arg:0, crc:0x65) + wait response
- CMD41 (arg:0x40000000, crc:0x77) + wait response
- repeat ACMD41 (CMD55 + CMD41)    forever.

The SDHC card never comes ready

I have tried  8GB  Sandisk and Transcend SDHC cards-- the result is the same.
Am I missing something here?  However I suspect the clock signal....

My question is to do with the SCLK signal.
Because it is generated by bit banging, it has an uneven mark-space ratio, that  dips below the 100kHz occasionally.

Has anyone successfully  used an SDHC card in SPI with a slower than 100kHz clock?  Or an uneven mark-space clock.

Unfortunately, it's not that easy for me to improve the clock speed with the bit banging method that I have in the code.

Thanks for any help.